# What is the boiling point and density of LSD?

Tags: boiling-point, drugs, density

I have tried to do a lot of research and didn't succeed to find the boiling point and density of LSD. I would want to know this information. In addition, I can't use Clausius–Clapeyron equation because I don't have the data that I would need to use that equation.

Comment: Bioorganic molecules usually don't have boiling points.

Comment: Why can't you use the Clausius-Clapeyron equation?

Comment: @CurtF. Because I don't have the data that the equation needs.

Comment: I think your question would be better if you explained that detail in the text of the question itself.

Comment: @CurtF. Good point, I edited it.

Comment: You want to distill it? That would be very impractical, use chromatography for purification. ☺

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lysergic acid diethylamide doesn't boil. It decomposes. The density is $1.2 \pm 0.1~\mathrm{g~cm^{-3}}$.

Data can be found at  [ChemSpider](http://chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.5558.html). There's a predicted boiling point of 541°C. However, lysergic acid decomposes at its melting point of about 240°C (CRC Handbook of Chemistry ad Physics, 64th ed.). This suggests that lysergic acid diethylamide does not have a real boiling point - at least at normal pressure.

Comment: Please cite your sources.

Comment: The statement about the boiling point is mainly common sense, given the structure and molecular weight of lysergic acid diethylamide. An additional argument is that lysergic acid decomposes at its melting point of about 240°C (CRC Handbook of Chemistry ad Physics, 64th ed.). The predicted boiling point of LSD is above 500°C[1] what is far above this temperature. The densitiy can also be found at[1].

[1] http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.5558.html

Comment: Concur, the decomposition is common sense, but supporting the argument with detail is a good idea. I recommend editing your answer to include the data and references of your comment.

Comment: … that's for lysergic acid. LSD itself (lysergide) has **m.p. 80–85 °C** (tartrate: 198–200 °C), no b.p. (ever measured?), as expected (Merck Index).